# Can I detect document saved (not changed) with Visual Studio Workspace in a VSIX?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, vsix

In my extension I use to tap into the document saved event using DTE:

```
this._events2 = (Events2)this._dte.Events;

//setup document events
this._documentEvents = this._events2.DocumentEvents;
this._documentEvents.DocumentSaved += _documentEvents_DocumentSaved;
```

I am migrating my extension to VS 2017 and want to start using the Roslyn stuff instead of DTE.  I figured out how to get the Visual Studio Workspace and tap into the [workspace changed event](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/WorkspaceChangeKind.cs,4e8698254ba7d256).  Now I have access to all these document events

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A document was added to the current solution.
    /// </summary>
    DocumentAdded = 9,

    /// <summary>
    /// A document was removed from the current solution.
    /// </summary>
    DocumentRemoved = 10,

    /// <summary>
    /// A document in the current solution was reloaded.
    /// </summary>
    DocumentReloaded = 11,

    /// <summary>
    /// A document in the current solution was changed.
    /// </summary>
    DocumentChanged = 12,
```

But there is no DocumentSaved.  DocumentChange fires every time a keystroke is made and DocumentReloaded never seems to fire at all.  Is it possible to detect just a document saved using the roslyn workspace events?

Comment: Roslyn has nothing to do with core VS actions like saving.  You need to work with the editor code, either via its MEF exports or COM interfaces (I'm not sure where saving is implemented).

Comment: Hmm, so according to the [Roslyn Project Doc](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-project-system) Visual Studio is using a new common project system based on Roslyn to replace the old DTE/Com stuff.  Roslyn compilers may not have anything to do with VS actions but this new Roslyn project system does and it works, I was able to use it to get the new solution and project events, just not the document event I am looking for.

Comment: The project system also has nothing to do with core VS actions like saving.  That replaces a different part of the old COM stuff (which are both entirely separate from DTE, which just wraps other old COM stuff).  You need to use the editor APIs directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To detect document save event( OnBeforeSave() or OnAfterSave() ) you can implement `IVsRunningDocTableEvents3` interface. You can do that by implementing this interface into a helper class and exposing a public event `event OnBeforeSaveHandler BeforeSave` and a public delegate `delegate void OnBeforeSaveHandler(object sender, Document document)`.

To catch this event just  : `runningDocTableEvents.BeforeSave += OnBeforeSave` and then you can write your code in the `OnBeforeSave` method.

My implementation of the `IVsRunningDocTableEvents3` interface look like this:

```
public class RunningDocTableEvents : IVsRunningDocTableEvents3
{
  #region Members

  private RunningDocumentTable mRunningDocumentTable;
  private DTE mDte;

  public delegate void OnBeforeSaveHandler(object sender, Document document);
  public event OnBeforeSaveHandler BeforeSave;

  #endregion

  #region Constructor

  public RunningDocTableEvents(Package aPackage)
  {
    mDte = (DTE)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE));
    mRunningDocumentTable = new RunningDocumentTable(aPackage);
    mRunningDocumentTable.Advise(this);
  }

  #endregion

  #region IVsRunningDocTableEvents3 implementation

  public int OnAfterAttributeChange(uint docCookie, uint grfAttribs)
  {
    return VSConstants.S_OK;
  }

  public int OnAfterAttributeChangeEx(uint docCookie, uint grfAttribs, IVsHierarchy pHierOld, uint itemidOld, string pszMkDocumentOld, IVsHierarchy pHierNew, uint itemidNew, string pszMkDocumentNew)
  {
    return VSConstants.S_OK;
  }

  public int OnAfterDocumentWindowHide(uint docCookie, IVsWindowFrame pFrame)
  {
    return VSConstants.S_OK;
  }

  public int OnAfterFirstDocumentLock(uint docCookie, uint dwRDTLockType, uint dwReadLocksRemaining, uint dwEditLocksRemaining)
  {
    return VSConstants.S_OK;
  }

  public int OnAfterSave(uint docCookie)
  {
    return VSConstants.S_OK;
  }

  public int OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(uint docCookie, int fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame)
  {
    return VSConstants.S_OK;
  }

  public int OnBeforeLastDocumentUnlock(uint docCookie, uint dwRDTLockType, uint dwReadLocksRemaining, uint dwEditLocksRemaining)
  {
    return VSConstants.S_OK;
  }

  public int OnBeforeSave(uint docCookie)
  {
    if (null == BeforeSave)
      return VSConstants.S_OK;

    var document = FindDocumentByCookie(docCookie);
    if (null == document)
      return VSConstants.S_OK;

    BeforeSave(this, FindDocumentByCookie(docCookie));
    return VSConstants.S_OK;
  }

  #endregion

  #region Private Methods

  private Document FindDocumentByCookie(uint docCookie)
  {
    var documentInfo = mRunningDocumentTable.GetDocumentInfo(docCookie);
    return mDte.Documents.Cast<Document>().FirstOrDefault(doc => doc.FullName == documentInfo.Moniker);
  }

  #endregion
}
```

I have used this implementation to format some documents when any kind of save command (CTRL + S, Save All, Compile, Build etc) from VS was triggered.

If you want to get the save event from a certain command like **Compile** you must add a check in your OnBeforeSave() method add some more code

First you must to keep a strong reference to **CommandEvents** `var vommandEvents = dte.Events.CommandEvents` and add a new method to the **CommandEvents** `commandEvents.BeforeExecute += CommandEventsBeforeExecute;`.

This will work because the **CommandsEvents** will always be called before the **BeforeSave**. This is how things works in Visual Studio, every action represents a command which requires some steps and events (Eg. Compile command contains in its workflow, before of anything, the save document event).

```
public override void OnBeforeSave(object sender, Document aDocument)
{
  if (false == myCompileCommandFlag)
    return;

  // write your code here 

}

public void CommandEventsBeforeExecute(string aGuid, int aId, object aCustomIn, object aCustomOut, ref bool aCancelDefault)
{
  string commandName = GetCommandName(aGuid, aId);
  if (0 != string.Compare("Build.Compile", commandName))
  {
    return;
  }
  myCompileCommandFlag= true;
}

public string GetCommandName(string aGuid, int aId)
{
  if (null == aGuid)
    return string.Empty;

  if (null == mCommand)
    return string.Empty;

  Command cmd = mCommand.Item(aGuid, aId);
  if (null == cmd)
    return string.Empty;

  return cmd.Name;
}
```

Comment: I have moved on from VS extension development so I can't confirm the answer is correct but if anyone else can let me know I will mark this as the solution

Comment: I want to mention that I have used the implementation above to format some documents when any kind of save command (CTRL + S, Save All, Compile, Build etc) from VS was triggered.

Comment: If you want to get the save event from a certain command like Compile you must add a check in your OnBeforeSave() method and get the command name. I updated my answear with an example for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have DTE2 interface and there you have `Events.DocumentEvents.DocumentSaved`
I didn't try it but its look promising.

Comment: Well, yes, I already actually do that.  I am using events2 and am able to get to the DocumentSaved there but this is using COM.  According to the [Roslyn Project Doc](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-project-system), Microsoft is moving away from the DTE/COM stuff to this new common project system.  I have successfully replace my project and solution events but when I came to documents I hit this issue.  I am just looking for the new Roslyn equivalently of the old DTE2 document saved event.